Change content language
I have 3 types of entities (University, Degree and Subject). Degree has a referencial field to university, and subjecs has referencial field to degree.
I have a custom twig template for a view to represent information about the selected degree.
My default lenguage is Spanish.
Initially, I have a list of universities, when I click on a univirsity, I access to the url /universidad/university_name. In this view all the degrees taken at the university appear. When I click on a degree, I access to the url /universidad/university_name/degree_name, and information about this degree is shown (I have the custom twig template). The problem is when I click on the language switcher, the content not change to the selected language.
I created the corresponding translations for the careers and universities. I have tried different ways to do it, but none of them worked.
For example, create a filter criteria as this one. I also tried the option "Interface text language selected for page", but not work. I tried other type of filters but none of them work.
In rendering language I select "Content language selected for page".
Some strange things that happen are:

In the initial list of universities, if I click on the one that is in English, and then on a degree, it takes me to the route https://prueba.ddev.site/en-gb/universidad/university-vigo/telecommunications-technology-engineering. If I click on Spanish in the language switcher the url becomes https://prueba.ddev.site/en-gb/universidad/university-vigo/telecommunications-technology-engineering?language=es. If now, I click again on language switcher to English, the the parameter ?language not change, remains with the value of 'es'.

If I do the same process, but starting from the beginning in Spanish, the route is
https://prueba.ddev.site/universidad/universidad-de-vigo/ingenieria-de-tecnologias-de-telecomunicacion, If I change the language in the language switcher, always change the ?language parameter, but the content not change the language.


I tried translate a basic page, and it work well, but the view I want to translate is not translated.
can someone help me?


Are you testing as an anonymous user or a logged-in user?  Often the logged-in user's language will override the language switcher (this is configurable).

Yes, I tested as an annonymous user (no log), but the content also is shown in Spanish (default language). If I an admin, the only things that change the language are de admin bars.
